# Java: Logging for multiple Threads with Log4j2

Tags: java, multithreading, sorting, log4j2

Let's say I have three classes A, B and C which are working in separate Threads (tA, tB, and tC) and all of them have also their own Instance of `Logger`.

Now I got a mess in the ouput because there is no order in the loggings of the three classes. Is there a possiblity to sort the loggings in the order of their appearance?

For example:

```
class A {
    public static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(A.class);

    public void start() {
        LOGGER.info("TestA");
        LOGGER.info("TestA");
        LOGGER.info("TestA");
    }
}

class B {
    public static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(B.class);

    public void start() {
        LOGGER.info("TestB");
        LOGGER.info("TestB");
        LOGGER.info("TestB");
    }
}

class A {
    public static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(C.class);

    public void start() {
        LOGGER.info("TestC");
        LOGGER.info("TestC");
        LOGGER.info("TestC");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
TestA
TestA
TestB
TestB
TestA
TestC
TestC
TestB
TestC
```

What I want is:

```
TestA
TestA
TestA
TestB
TestB
TestB
TestC
TestC
TestC
```

Comment: What do you mean there is no order? Don't you add timestamps to your log output? And threads by definition run async from eachother, that's their purpose. Please post an example of your output, and how you'd like the output to show up.

Comment: If your requirement is serial execution and thus serial logs, then dont use threading, execute them sequentially like `new A().start(); new B().start()` so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since logging is by definition time-based, it doesn't make even sense to try to think that you could achieve something like that (well, without additional work of course).

What you can do is add the [thread ID](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/layouts.html) to the logging layout. Then you can use other tools (e.g. `grep`) to isolate the logging for the specific threads you wish to see, or even sort the log by the thread ID which would give you the logs for each thread sequentially.